# Class method process memory collision on sigterm handler

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Let's take a look at the following code snippet:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import signal
import os
import sys

class Name:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("init {} -> name:{} obj:{}".format(self.name, hex(id(self.name)), hex(id(self))))
        signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.sigterm_handler)
    def run(self):
        while True:
            print("run {} -> name:{} obj:{}".format(self.name, hex(id(self.name)), hex(id(self))))
            time.sleep(1)
    def sigterm_handler(self, _signo, _stack_frame):
        print("exit {} -> name:{} obj:{}".format(self.name, hex(id(self.name)), hex(id(self))))
        os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)

m1 = Name("alice")
p1 = mp.Process(target=m1.run)

p1.start()
m2 = Name("bob")


time.sleep(2)
p1.terminate()
```

Here is the corresponding output:

```
init alice -> name:0x7f8ee6036500 obj:0x7f8ee5dc2710
init bob -> name:0x7f8ee5dc2730 obj:0x7f8ee5dc2828
run alice -> name:0x7f8ee6036500 obj:0x7f8ee5dc2710
run alice -> name:0x7f8ee6036500 obj:0x7f8ee5dc2710
exit alice -> name:0x7f8ee6036500 obj:0x7f8ee5dc2710
```

---

Now, let's start `p1` just after creating `m2`, such as this:

```py
m1 = Name("alice")
p1 = mp.Process(target=m1.run)

m2 = Name("bob")
p1.start()

time.sleep(2)
p1.terminate()
```

Here is what we get:

```
init alice -> name:0x7fa77c4c5500 obj:0x7fa77c2516d8
init bob -> name:0x7fa77c2516f8 obj:0x7fa77c2517b8
run alice -> name:0x7fa77c4c5500 obj:0x7fa77c2516d8
run alice -> name:0x7fa77c4c5500 obj:0x7fa77c2516d8
exit bob -> name:0x7fa77c2516f8 obj:0x7fa77c2517b8
```

---

The important thing to note is that the last line changed from `alice` to `bob`. It seems like `sigterm_handler` is replaced by the one from the new class instance, but that's not the case with `run`.

Why is that?

Comment: You are setting the global signal handler when you create the object, not when you start a process to run a method bound to that object.